# Using perl in windows oddities

Tags: perl, batch-file

I've got windows bat file, (using activeperl)

```
@echo off
perl -p -e 's/DIV\[/div\[/g' orginal.txt > output.txt
perl -p -e 'rename("output.txt", "orginal.txt")';
...
```

Running a .bat file, and I just cant get it to run properly..

```
Can't open ;: No such file or directory, <> line 12248.
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 4):

You can't use single-quotes to enclose the Perl code in Windows. As a result, you need to escape the double-quotes or find other alternatives, such as `qq(...)`.

```
perl -pe "s/DIV\[/div\[/g" original.txt > output.txt
perl -pe "rename(qq(output.txt), qq/original.txt/)"
```

Note that in this case, the arguments to `rename` can simply be `rename('a.txt', 'b.txt')` since they are literals and no variable interpolation is required.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to use double quotes to quote the program text under Windows cmd. In your example, you can just swiztch double and single quotes. In cases where you really need double quotes in the perl text, use qq{ .... } instead.

Answer (score 1):

The other posters are correct: windows requires double quotes for `-e` scripts to perl, which often screws things up. There is one more thing you can do, though: Use the `-i` switch, like this:

```
@echo off
perl -pi.bak -we "s/DIV\[/div\[/g" original.txt
```

The `-i.bak` switch will edit the file in place - no rename required - AND it will store a backup of the file in "original.txt.bak". If you do not want a backup, remove the "`.bak`" part and just use `-pi`.

Comment: and to remove the .bak file through perl?

Comment: Well, if you are thinking of removing it in the same script, just don't add it in the first place. Just use `perl -pi -we`. In perl, you would use `unlink 'original.txt.bak'`. In a batch file, it would be simpler to use `del original.txt.bak'`

Comment: I've noticed a bug in this, not sure how easy it is.. but seems to convert the file into dos, the source file is unix (which I want to keep)